# How to work around 'no LastInsertId available' using beego/orm

Tags: postgresql, go, beego

I am trying to use https://github.com/astaxie/beego/tree/master/orm to insert a `struct` into a postgres database. The operation should be simple

```
import "github.com/astaxie/beego/orm"

type Product struct {
    ID string `orm:"pk"`
    ...
}

product := &Product{ID: productID}
_, err := orm.NewOrm().Insert(product)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
```

I keep getting this; `no LastInsertId available` whenever the code runs (the insert is otherwise successful) but I get a crash. 
I understand is it due to postgresql limitations because I use https://www.github.com/lib/pq driver.

Is there I way to work around this using beego/orm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the crash is being caused by your `log.Fatal(err)`, you can avoid this by checking and avoiding it:

```
_, err := orm.NewOrm().Insert(product)

if err != nil {
    if err.Error() == "no LastInsertId available" {
        log.Println(err)
    } else {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}
```